# Is it safe to put database login details in my App?

Tags: java, mysql, swift, security

Can reverse engineering it can make it easy to hack?
Any another way to do it safely?

I'm talking about both android and iOS apps.

Comment: its very easy to reverse engineer java

Comment: No, this is not safe. Anyone can get this info, no matter how you try to hide it. Even a read-only account is a security issue. You should have a backend server that only allows operations you need, and have your apps go through that.

Comment: Why would your app need the password to the remote database? Your app won't be talking directly to the database.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, it is not safe.

Anyone can look into your code or spy on network traffic and just read the credentials.

What you should do is to make a call (as usual) to your application server and there internally have needed information available.